How can I create scrollable tabs using Jetpack Compose?
I want to create the kind of "tabs" that Whatsapp has (all, unread, groups) whatsapp tab image but they also have to be scrollable. But, I am not sure what the tabs are even called since the width for each "tab" is sized according to the width of the title. How can I achieve this using Jetpack Compose?
Thank you and I really appreciate the help!

You can use Buttons or Chips in a scrollable Row. Does this answer your question?

A FilterChip might be what you are looking for. You can put them into a Row and apply the horizontalScroll Modifier to make the Row scrollable if the FilterChips exceed the screen width.
Please try the following code:
@Composable
fun FilterChipExample() {

    val filterLabels = remember {
        listOf("All", "Unread", "Groups")
    }

    var selectedIndex by remember {
        mutableIntStateOf(-1)
    }

    Column {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {
            filterLabels.forEachIndexed() { thisIndex, filterLabel ->
                FilterChip(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        selectedIndex = if (selectedIndex == thisIndex) {
                            -1
                        } else {
                            thisIndex
                        }
                              },
                    label = {
                        Text(filterLabel)
                    },
                    selected = selectedIndex == thisIndex
                )
            }
        }

        when(selectedIndex) {
            0 -> {
                Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp), text = "Showing all Chats...")
            }
            1 -> {
                Text(text = "Showing unread Chats...")
            }
            2 -> {
                Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp), text = "Showing Groups...")
            }
            else -> {
                Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp), text = "Nothing selected")
            }
        }
    }
}

Output:


Thank you so much for this! Really appreciate it!

You can use ScrollableTabRow
val tabTitles = List(10) { "Tab $it" }
var selectedTabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

ScrollableTabRow(
    selectedTabIndex = selectedTabIndex,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
) {
    tabTitles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
        Tab(
            text = { Text(title) },
            selected = selectedTabIndex == index, 
            onClick = { selectedTabIndex = index },
        )
    }
}

You might not like the default indicator for the selected tab, but you can look into how they implemented it by going to the ScrollableTabRow implementation and creating your own.
You also can easily change the Tab(...) to anything else you want.
If you use a HorizontalPager, use its state to determine the selected tab index and its offset to determine the indicator position (That is optional).
I can share an example with a pager if you want.

Although that are scrollable tabs, what was actually asked for looks quite different. Why not just use Buttons (with RoundedCornerShape) in a simple, scrollable Row?

@Leviathan Your point is completely valid, I once needed something custom and used a Row with a scrolling modifier. However, a ScrollableTabRow auto-scrolls to the selected tab and makes sure it is visible on the screen (If you are using a HorizontalPager that is very important as the user will swipe left and write and the ScrollableTabRow will make sure the selected tab is always visible). However, with a Row, you would need to handle this yourself. I would not say it is something hard, but it complicates it. So in the worst case, I copy the ScrollableTabRow and modify it to my liking!
